# Shrinkwrap a horizontally-wrapping variable-height auto grid

Tags: css, flexbox, css-grid

I'm trying to achieve the following layout for a component on my page:

[image]

My constraints:

- The left content area will contain user-supplied text and is therefore of unknown height.
- The right section contains a variable number of items which should wrap to multiple columns when they would extend beyond the height of the left content if constrained to a single column.
- When the right section items wrap, full columns should equal the height of the left content section.
- The content of each of the items in the right section will have a fixed, equal height; however, the items themselves are allowed to vary in height, especially in order to fulfill the previous requirement.
- Each item should always have the same height as every other item in the right section.
- The left section will have a max-width.
- The outer wrapper should be shrinkwrapped so that the whole component can be centered on the page.

It seemed logical to use flexbox for the outer wrapper and grid for the small items on the right side. [I've almost got it working here.](https://codepen.io/narthur/pen/rPYaeN) Unfortunately, the behavior of the grid is very unpredictable. Depending on the viewport width, sometimes it wraps properly, sometimes it doesn't. Sometimes it overflows the outer wrapper. And often it takes up more space than it needs.

Here's the code I have so far:

HTML:

```
<div class="outer">
  <div class="content">
    Turnip greens yarrow ricebean rutabaga endive cauliflower sea lettuce kohlrabi amaranth water spinach avocado daikon napa cabbage asparagus winter purslane kale. Celery potato scallion desert raisin horseradish spinach carrot soko. Lotus root water spinach fennel kombu maize bamboo shoot green bean swiss chard seakale pumpkin onion chickpea gram corn pea. Brussels sprout coriander water chestnut gourd swiss chard wakame kohlrabi beetroot carrot watercress. Corn amaranth salsify bunya nuts nori azuki bean chickweed potato bell pepper artichoke. Turnip greens yarrow ricebean rutabaga endive cauliflower sea lettuce kohlrabi amaranth water spinach avocado daikon napa cabbage asparagus winter purslane kale. Celery potato scallion desert raisin horseradish spinach carrot soko. Lotus root water spinach fennel kombu maize bamboo shoot green bean swiss chard seakale pumpkin onion chickpea gram corn pea. Brussels sprout coriander water chestnut gourd swiss chard wakame kohlrabi beetroot carrot watercress. Corn amaranth salsify bunya nuts nori azuki bean chickweed potato bell pepper artichoke. 
  </div>
  <div class="grid">
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
.outer {
  border: 5px solid black;
  display: flex;
  max-width: 100%;
  flex: 0 1 auto;
  img {
    flex: 0 0 auto;
  }
}
.content {
  padding: 1rem;
}
.grid {
  writing-mode: vertical-lr;
  padding: 1rem;
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 1rem;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(60px, 1fr));
  grid-auto-rows: 60px;
}
.item {
  writing-mode: horizontal-tb;
  background-color: gray;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  &::after {
    content: "#";
    color: white;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 2rem;
    padding: .5em;
    display: block;
  }
}
```

How can I achieve this layout?

Comment: Your codepen demo works well in Chrome. Where are you having problems?

Comment: @Michael_B Hmm, strange. When I load my pen in Chrome, the component takes the entire width of the screen even when it shouldn't. And resizing the window makes things jump around like crazy. Are you not seeing those behaviors?

Comment: I am seeing the jumping around. On the other issue, have you tried inline level containers instead? (i.e., `display: inline-flex`)